# Locally isomorphic singularities = Locally isomorphic minimal blow-ups?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, singularity-theory

Let's say that one has two varieties $V_1, V_2$, with singularities at points $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively, and that there exist open neighbourhoods $U_1$ and $U_2$ of these singularities such that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are isomorphic, i.e. such that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are locally isomorphic around their singularities.

Is it then always a given that if we have minimal resolutions $W_1$ and $W_2$ of $V_1$ and $V_2$ at these singularities, then around the exceptional divisors $D_1$ and $D_2$, there exists open neighbourhoods $U'_1$ and $U'_2$ such that $U'_1$ and $U'_2$ are isomorphic?

Further, if this is the case, is it then a given that $\mathcal{O}_{W_1} (U'_1) \cong \mathcal{O}_{W_2} (U'_2)$?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to ask about locally homeomorphic singularities instead of locally isomorphic singularities?

Comment: I originally wrote "isomorphic", but then I figured that since a singularity is a geometric object, I should be using "homeomorphic." Now that you point this out to me I am less sure that that was the proper judgement to make. But, thinking two more rounds, I realized that when we talk of varieties, we do not merely talk about topological isomorphism, we talk about isomorphic of the algebraic structure as well. Therefore, I shall immediately edit my comment to properly reflect this, as you are right that it should indeed be "isomorphic" as opposed to "homeomorphic"!

Comment: FYI "isomorphism" is a generic term in category theory that is in some sense always appropriate, despite the fact that we also use isomorphism within specific categories. So for example, a bijection is a set isomorphism; a homeomorphism is a topological isomorphism; and a diffeomorphism is an isomorphism in the smooth category.